# Gmail search operators not returning expected results

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I'm trying to filter out unread messages that are *not* in my inbox, and thought that `-in:inbox  in:unread` should be sufficient. However, this is returning some (but not all) emails that *are* in my inbox.

Is there anything about these emails that's likely to be a bit weird? Like the one in the example below, they don't have any other labels attached to them

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `in:unread` it should be `is:unread`.

Reference

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Comment: I've tried this - it still returns the emails that _are_ in the inbox